# Unable to Consume service made on salesforce

Tags: apex

I created a service as below:

```
global class HelloWorldWebService{
    webService static string sayHello(){
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}
```

I generate a wsdl for this service:
https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/wsdl/class/HelloWorldWebService

When I consume this URL in SOAPUI it throws below error:

[image]

Comment: is your wsdl file valid? do you have any errors with [validator](https://www.wsdl-analyzer.com/) ?

Comment: I called that service from another apex class via visualforce page and it is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this WSDL is not public, you can't give the WSDL URL directly in SoapUI while creating a project. You have to save it in local (as WSDL file) and provide the WSDL file path in SoapUI while creating the project.

To call this service you have to use Login method present in enterprise/partner WSDL. First, you have to call the Login method to get the session I'd, then pass it to your web service and get the output.

For more details please check this link http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/using-soapui-with-salesforce-to-test-standard-and-custom-web-services-response/

Comment: Hi Saroj, thanks for your response.I saved the wsdl file in my local system and now I am able to consume the service in SOAP UI. But unable to call this service, my partial input request for wsdl file is as below:       
   <hel:CallOptions>
         <hel:client>?</hel:client>
      </hel:CallOptions>
      <hel:SessionHeader>
         <hel:sessionId>?</hel:sessionId>
      </hel:SessionHeader>  what should I pass in client element and sessionId element ?

Comment: I did not find any username and password element in my wsdl file.

Comment: @RaamKothiyal As I already explained, you can't consume the service directly. You have to first consume the Enterprise WSDL, where you will get the login method. Pass username, password and security token and get the session id. Pass this session Id in your Webservice URL. You have to change the endpoint also. You can follow the steps as explained in this link http://www.jitendrazaa.com/blog/salesforce/using-soapui-with-salesforce-to-test-standard-and-custom-web-services-response/

Comment: Hi Saroj, In response msg I got my session id: 00D7F0000001F69!AQ4AQDnEz.ZcddmS9EnxW0WAO2vzLr9gFS2vTVHRS8.HAmr_E5G9ltkC6yv617lKY4OQoVXOIoc2iq4D.QG8Nv.7vbQZX33z and server URL : https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/Soap/c/40.0/00D7F0000001F69/0DF7F0000001htf , in soap UI , for my web service I update the server URL and seesion id, but I got the error: No operation available for request {http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/HelloWorldWebService}sayHello , even I changed the response URL to https://ap5.salesforce.com/services/Soap/s/40.0/00D7F0000001F69/0DF7F0000001htf but no luck.

Comment: is there any wrong with my web service, I have mentioned the code in my question. Plz have a look !

Comment: Don't change the ServerURL. Keep the Old URL generated in SoapUI because the WSDL already has the correct service URL in it. Try only with updating the session ID.

Comment: Hi Saroj, Thanks for the response.I remove the optional elements in request message and got my response successfully. Just have a query what values we need to fill categories element :<hel:DebuggingHeader>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <hel:categories>
            <hel:category>?</hel:category>
            <hel:level>?</hel:level>
         </hel:categories>
         <hel:debugLevel>?</hel:debugLevel>
      </hel:DebuggingHeader>
and what we need to put on clientOptions element:<hel:CallOptions>
         <hel:client>?</hel:client>
      </hel:CallOptions>

Comment: Hi Saroh, I have some doubt,please clear my doubt: In real scenario when a third party application consume our service then we have to provide session id to third party. Because this session id is changed after some time, so every time third party will change their session id. Can we increase the expire time of session id ? What is the default expire time of session id.

Comment: No, you don't have to increase the session time. In the real scenario, you have to create one Salesforce user to make callouts from the external app into Salesforce. So the external app that accesses Salesforce through the API must first log in as a Salesforce user for authentication. Assign this user with only required permissions to perform certain operations required by the app. See this Salesforce Knowledge Article for more details https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000176281&type=1

Comment: If this answer has solved your question you can use the checkmark next to it to mark it as such. That will help others who are looking at it to locate the accepted solution.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60506/discussion-between-raam-kothiyal-and-saroj-bera).